# Fractional Second precision in DBMSs

Tags: sql, rdbms, precision, fractions, time-precision

I would like to know what `Fractional Second Precision` is, with some examples.
And how different DBMSs support it?

Comment: why downvoting my question ? is there a problem with it ? So just tell me to fix it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) Sql Server 2008 and newer has `DATETIME2` which is has precision of 100ns

> Character length 19 positions minimum (YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss ) to 27
>   maximum (YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.0000000)

---

> Precision, scale 0 to 7 digits, with an accuracy of 100ns. The default
>   precision is 7 digits.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx

---

[mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) - MySQL 5.6.4

> MySQL 5.6.4 and up expands fractional seconds support for TIME,
>   DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP values, with up to microseconds (6 digits)
>   precision:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html

Comment: Thank you very much @Vladimir Oselesky :) Do you have any information on the support of MySQL for the fractional second precision ?

Comment: MariaDB also supports **[microsecond accuracy](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/microseconds-in-mariadb/)**, since version 5.3.

Comment: Can anyone tell me where the default precision of 7 digits is documented?  The page this answer linked to does not say that (unless I missed it) and I haven't been able to find a definitive definition of the default fractional seconds precision.